# how to select category as well in freebase search widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, freebase

i was using Freebase Search Widget for my project, using it i can select the word from the suggestion list in my input box, but how to get the category as well in another text box ?

Example: http://suggest-examples.freebaseapps.com/

If i type: James Cameron, it will be selected in the text box, but i also want the category to be selected in another text box ?

Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myinput").suggest({
    key: "YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE",
    filter:'(all type:/film/director)'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Freebase Search widget](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-widget) uses the [Freebase Search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview) to suggest entities. So When you type "james cameron" into the input field, you're sending the following Search API request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=james+cameron&exact=false&prefixed=true
```

You can see in the responses from that API call that it passes back the name, ID, a ranking and what the entity is notable for:

```
{
  "mid": "/m/03_gd",
  "id": "/en/james_cameron",
  "name": "James Cameron",
  "notable": {
    "name": "Film Director",
    "id": "/m/02jknp"
  },
  "lang": "en",
  "score": 629.205872
},...
```

All of this data is accessible from the jQuery callback in the Search widget like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#myinput").suggest({
    key: "YOUR-API-KEY-GOES-HERE",
    filter:'(all type:/film/director)'
  }).bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
    alert(data.name + ", " + data.id + " (" + data.notable.name + ")");
  });
});
```

In this case, James Cameron ([/m/03_gd](http://www.freebase.com/m/03_gd)) is notable for being a film director ([/m/02jknp](http://www.freebase.com/m/02jknp)).